# Changing values in a theano tensor vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I have a theano tensor vector `next_probs` something like `[0.222, 0.34342, 0.41324, 0.1231, ...]`, which is the output of the following function:

```
next_probs = tensor.nnet.softmax(logit)
```

`logit` is a vector which has the same dimension as `next_probs`.

How can I change one specific value to `1`, and the others to `0` in `next_probs` vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value specifically you want to change? if you just want have a vector which have same dimension as `next_probs` you can use `zeros` and `set_subtensor` like below

```
ret = T.zeros(next_probs.shape)
ret = T.set_subtensor(ret[index],1)
```

If you want to use this in classification model, and you need the class with highest probability in `next_probs` become 1 and the others become 0 this is my other answer:

```
ret = T.zeros(next_probs.shape)
ret = T.set_subtensor(ret[T.argmax(next_probs)],1)
```

`ret` is a vector with 1 in the class with highest probability, and 0 for the others

Comment: I got a dimension error: IndexError: index out of bounds
Apply node that caused the error: IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;int64}(Alloc.0, TensorConstant{1}, Constant{9})
Toposort index: 63
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(int8, scalar), Scalar(int64)]
Inputs shapes: [(1, 26942), (), ()]
Inputs strides: [(107768, 4), (), ()]
Inputs values: ['not shown', array(1, dtype=int8), 9]
Outputs clients: [[Softmax(IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;int64}.0)]]